# How do I use a local HTTPS URL in java?

Tags: java, https, certificate

Using the Java URL class, I can connect to an external `HTTPS` server (such as our production site), but using a local URL I get following exception.

```
"SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
```

How do I get a valid certification path?

EDIT: I'm not using this URL to directly create a connection, I am passing the URL to an `itext` `PDFReader`, which is then having the connection issue.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to setup a [`HostnameVerifier`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html). Before connecting, you need add it to the connection object

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    // check hostname/session
    return true;
  }
});
conn.connect();
// read/write...
```

There certainly are some implementations out there, if you need one. You might want to look at [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) project too.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to look at is the `TrustManager` you are using. The error message suggests that the certificate presented by the server is not signed by a trusted root. Since you don't have direct control over the SSL socket that is created, I think your best bet is to [initialize](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init(javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[],%20javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[],%20java.security.SecureRandom)) your own `SSLContext` with a `TrustManager` that's been [setup with the root](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory.html#init(java.security.KeyStore)) CA of the server's certificate chain. Then set this context as the [default](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#setDefault(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)).

This is assuming you are using Java 6. The API is more limited in Java 5. You can get a default `SSLSocketFactory`, but there's no standard way to set it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's complaining about is that when you create an SSL connection, the server must present a valid certificate to the client.  You can write an appropriate endpoint in Java (HTTPServerSocket will do it I think) but it would require some hacking about to set it up.  It's probably easier to set up a local web server with anything that handles SSL correctly --- Apache, lighttp, whatever --- and create a self-signed cert using the openssl tools.

Updated

Here's an example from the Java Almanac. http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/Server.html

An SSL server socket requires certificates that it will send to clients for authentication. The certificates must be contained in a keystore whose location must be explicitly specified (there is no default). Following the example we describe how to create and specify a keystore for the SSL server socket to use.

```
try {
    int port = 443;
    ServerSocketFactory ssocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    ServerSocket ssocket = ssocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);

    // Listen for connections
    Socket socket = ssocket.accept();

    // Create streams to securely send and receive data to the client
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

    // Read from in and write to out...

    // Close the socket
    in.close();
    out.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
}
```

Specify the keystore of certificates using the javax.net.ssl.keyStore system property:

```
> java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 MyServer
```

Comment: I have a working HTTPS server running, I just can't connect to it with the java URL class (updating main post to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

It may also help you to add the certificate that the localhost server is using (I assume it's self-signed) to the JVM's [keystore](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/keystore.html), [using the "keytool" utility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html). This should have the effect of telling the JVM "you can trust this certificate".

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up running a static method (only on dev) that installs a very trusting TrustManager (accepts everything), and also added a hostnameVerifier that always returns true (thanks [sblundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893/sblundy)).