# Jsoup HTTPS connecting

Tags: java, ssl, authentication, https, jsoup

So, I'm trying to log into a site, save the cookies and connect to another site while providing the cookies and proceed to scrape the website. All using Jsoup and regular java (I plan to move to Android later on). My problem is, that the site with the loginform is using https and there I am getting [a ton of errors](http://pastebin.com/hK0wsVzR). After searching around I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744075). The method described involving getting the SSL certificate from the login-site and change the extension from .crt to .jks. However, I keep getting the errors and therefore unable to make it work. Here's my code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

                //Log in
                Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect("https://login.emu.dk")
                                .data("login", "myUsername")
                                .data("pass", "myPassword")
                                .method(Method.POST)
                                .execute();

                //Keep logged in
                Map<String,String> loginCookies = login.cookies();

                ArrayList<Lesson> unsorted = new ArrayList<Lesson>();
                URL elevplan = new URL("https://elevplan.dk");
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser();

                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/Users/philipjakobsen/Desktop/login.emu.dk.jks");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/Users/philipjakobsen/Desktop/login.emu2.dk.jks");

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://elevplan.dk")
                .cookies(loginCookies)
                .get();
```

So, does anyone know how to allow Jsoup to make https connections? As earlier said, I would like to "port" my application to Android, and in this scenario I don't think it is possible to use a static certificate(?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you can connect to elevplan.dk? Your error message points to a DNS error that's not HTTPS related.

Comment: When connecting to elevplan.dk I get redirected to 

https://www.elevplan.dk/offentlig/default.aspx?wmDetect=ok&flash=1,0,,&colordepth=32&sw=1280&sh=1024

But actually you're right. login.emu.dk is the site that's giving me a bunch of cookies and I get redirected from login.emu.dk to 

https://www.elevplan.dk/Moduler/Elevforside/Elevforside.aspx?elevid=1911024

Aka my personal version of the site. When I change all elevplan.dk to the URL of the personal version I still get the errors.

Does anyone know how to use Apache's HttpClient instead of JSoup for the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following (just put it before Jsoup.connect("https://login.emu.dk"):

```
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
```