# Connecting to Iframe using JSoup

Tags: java, iframe, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to connect using the credentials in this page:

https://www.particulares.santandertotta.pt/bepp/sanpt/usuarios/loginrefeicao/0,,,0.shtml

And it redirects to a new page:

https://www.particulares.santandertotta.pt/pagina/indice/0,,841_1_2,00.html

That contains an Iframe wich have the information i need. The url of the Iframe is:

https://www.particulares.santandertotta.pt/bepp/sanpt/tarjetas/listadomovimientostarjetarefeicao/0,,,0.shtml

The problem is that i can't connect to that page. The code i'm using to enter this Iframe is this one

```
//the variable 'data' are the credentials stored in a map
Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.particulares.santandertotta.pt/bepp/sanpt/tarjetas/listadomovimientostarjetarefeicao/0,,,0.shtml").data(data).timeout(15000).method(Method.GET).execute();
```

Everytime i run this code and parse the result it gives me some kind of message saying my access was denied due to security reasons for maintaining the connection for a long period of time.

Could someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744075/how-to-connect-via-https-using-jsoup

Comment: @webaib i don't have any exception

Comment: @DiogoPinheiro did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

In this kind of situation, Jsoup may be doing something wrong. In order to find what's going on under the cover, follow those steps:

#### Step 1 / Fire up your favorite browser

Empty its cache. Start your developer console and ask it to show you every requests done by your browser AND the headers exchanged between it and the server. IMO, you may use a more convinient tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) in order to spy on your browser requests.

#### Step 2/ Let your code with Jsoup runs

Now it's time to spy on your code with Jsoup. Again use a tool like Fiddler for getting the requests and the headers exchanged by your code and the server.

#### Step 3/ Compare the spied requests

For each requests made by your browser and your Jsoup code compare them side by side. Compare the headers exchanged side by side. You may find that a cookie set by the server is not resent by Jsoup. You may find that the server tries to challenge your code and it fails while your browser passes the challenge...

Let the force be with you... ;)