# Jsoup connection to https(keystore)

Tags: java, https, jsoup, keystore, truststore

I have a problem with connection(login) to https://jizdenky.regiojet.cz/Login?0.

**Code:**

```
//add certificate to trustStore
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystore/regionjet.jks");
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("https://jizdenky.regiojet.cz/Login?0");
Connection.Response response = connection.data("passwordAccountCode", username).data("password", password).method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
```

and i still get exception with certification path

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Anyone could help me or telling me where is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do **two things**. *I am just reffering* here to also answered questions.

### Generally allow all certificates

Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/3977134

And the corresponding code is:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCertificates = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null; // Not relevant.
        }
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            // Do nothing. Just allow them all.
        }
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            // Do nothing. Just allow them all.
        }
    }
};

HostnameVerifier trustAllHostnames = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true; // Just allow them all.
    }
};

try {
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCertificates, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(trustAllHostnames);
}
catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
}
```

### Add the certificate to the store of your JRE

This method requires you to download the `CRT` file from e.g. your browser. After that you should include it into your JRE using the `keytool` command which is part of the JRE.

A complete answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745706/3977134