# How to turn of the SSL certificate and get Login response using JSOUP/Rest Assured Api?

Tags: java, testing, ssl-certificate, jsoup, rest-assured

***When i tried turning off the ssl certificate validation in Postman,i got the response but iam not sure how to turn off the ssl certificate validation through code**

I have used **below code (JSOUP)** and i am getting **"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:"**

```
    public String  Login () throws Exception {
            Connection.Response response = (Connection.Response) Jsoup.connect("url").ignoreContentType(true)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .data("login_submit","Log In", "password","Password1","username","batman","Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                      .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                      .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                    .execute();
            System.out.println(response.cookie("PHPSESSID"));
            return response.cookie("PHPSESSID");

        }

**Stacktrace:**


    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
        at lib.dataObject.dataCleanup.DeprecateOrganizations.Login(DeprecateOrganizations.java:24)
        at lib.dataObject.dataCleanup.Login.login(Login.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 46 more*
```

Please tell me a way to get login response.

Comment: which java version are you using??

Comment: I am using Java 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect via HTTPS using Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744075/how-to-connect-via-https-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the TLS certificate validation by adding the following to your connect statement:

```
.validateTLSCertificates(false)
```

like:

```
Jsoup.connect("url").validateTLSCertificates(false)
```

Comment: Jsoup.connect("url").validateTLSCertificates(false) **has been deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

**I finally found the answer** used the below function before my Login function

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class DeprecateOrganizations {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public void disableSSLCertCheck() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
        };
```