# How can I effectively use a JKS file from IntelliJ's resources folder?

Tags: ssl, intellij-idea, kotlin, jsoup

I am developing a Kotlin project in IntelliJ that needs to access an HTTPS-enabled website using Jsoup. Testing uncovered a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`, so I saved the security certificate for the site and made a JKS file. Since I can't make guarantees about the JVM that'll be running the eventual JAR file, I thought it'd be best to save the JKS file in the resources folder and load it in the program. Nevertheless, when I test this function:

```
fun getHomePage(): Connection.Response {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/resources/certificate.jks")
    return Jsoup.connect("https://www.something.com/")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute()
}
```

...I still get the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1974)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:345)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:339)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1968)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1777)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1098)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processRecord(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1137)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
[...]
```

I imagine I need something other than `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/resources/certificate.jks")` (courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745706/990549) here. I just don't know what.