# problem java jsoup error to connect https?

Tags: jsoup

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    done
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
    at DescargaModulos.Prueba1.main(Prueba1.java:101)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 53 seconds)
```

My code:
jsoup 1.11.3 and jdk 1.8

```
String url = "https://intranet:8106/ctx/jsp/index.jsp";
Connection.Response respuesta = Jsoup.connect(url)
      .data(cabezeras)
      .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
      .method(Connection.Method.GET)
      .execute();
```

---->KO

for url = "https://gtihub.com" -> OK

Thanks

Comment: Hello, can you edit your question properly and make it easier to understand. Make sure to clearly state what you tried

Comment: The problem is not related to Jsoup. There is problem with connection. You can have a look for  example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62929/6578434

Comment: You are using ssl. Check if you have proper certificates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect via HTTPS using Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744075/how-to-connect-via-https-using-jsoup)